# Transformar linhas em coluna de um select - PIVOT - SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, pivot

Tenho uma consulta SQL que retorna o seguinte resultado:

**Consulta**

```
      +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |  CONJUNTO   | TIPO  | FILHO  |  PAI   | TIPO_CONTEUDO   | TIPO_DESCRICAO |
      +-------------|-------|--------|--------|-----------------|----------------+
      |  8005       | 150   |   40   |  NULL  | 1               | ORDEM          |
      |  8005       | 150   |   41   |  NULL  | 2               | ORDEM          |
      |  8005       | 150   |   42   |  NULL  | 3               | ORDEM          |
      |  8005       | 201   |   43   |  40    | 2005            | ANO            |
      |  8005       | 202   |   44   |  40    | 10              | MES            |
      |  8005       | 203   |   45   |  40    | 101010          | NUMERO         |
      |  8005       | 204   |   46   |  40    | ST 1            | SETOR          |
      |  8005       | 205   |   47   |  40    | TESTE 1         | TIPO           |
      |  8005       | 201   |   48   |  41    | 2006            | ANO            |
      |  8005       | 202   |   49   |  41    | 11              | MES            |
      |  8005       | 203   |   50   |  41    | 202020          | NUMERO         |
      |  8005       | 204   |   51   |  41    | ST 2            | SETOR          |
      |  8005       | 205   |   52   |  41    | TESTE 2         | TIPO           |
      |  8005       | 201   |   53   |  42    | 2007            | ANO            |
      |  8005       | 202   |   54   |  42    | 12              | MES            |
      |  8005       | 203   |   55   |  42    | 303030          | NUMERO         |
      |  8005       | 204   |   56   |  42    | ST 3            | SETOR          |
      |  8005       | 205   |   57   |  42    | TESTE 3         | TIPO           |
      +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Porém quero que algumas linhas dependo da regra que irei explicar mais embaixo seja retornado como coluna.

**Resultado**

```
  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
  | CONJUNTO    | TIPO_CONTEUDO | ANO    |  MÊS  |  NUMERO  |   SETOR   | TIPO    |
  +-------------|---------------|--------|-------|----------|-----------|---------+    
  | 8005        | 1             | 2005   |  10   |  101010  |   ST 1    | TESTE 1 |
  | 8005        | 2             | 2006   |  11   |  202020  |   ST 2    | TESTE 2 |
  | 8005        | 3             | 2007   |  12   |  303030  |   ST 3    | TESTE 3 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Descrição**

- O select é filtrado pelo CONJUNTO (no caso 8005).
- Caso o registro tenha o campo PAI igual a NULL ele fica sendo um novo registro relacionado ao seu FILHO junto com o conteudo de TIPO_CONTEUDO (ORDEM).
- Caso o registro tenha o campo PAI diferente de NULL ele deve ser vinculado ao PAI respectivo.
- A coluna TIPO é o ID do TIPO_DESCRICAO (TIPO_DESCRICAO foi adicionado por mim pois na tabela original nao tem).

Desculpe caso não entendam as regras, mas resumindo, irei vincular os CONJUNTOS FILHOS ao PAI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que o agrupamento que você quer fazer é realizado por 3 colunas: a coluna `conjunto`, `pai` e `filho`. No caso do `PIVOT` os resultados são agrupados pelas colunas que serão selecionadas em uma `subquery` **EXCETO** pela coluna que será utilizada como **VALOR** e pela coluna que conterá as subdivisões. Note também que você quer 3 registros que tem em comum os código 40, 41 e 42 que estão na coluna `pai`. Caso a referida coluna não esteja preenchida, os valores que são considerados importantes para o agrupamento (além da `conjunto`) são os da coluna `filho`. Portanto você só precisa utilizar a função `ISNULL` para selecionar a informação que é importante para o agrupamento da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT y.conjunto,
       y.ordem AS tipo_conteudo,
       y.ano,
       y.mes,
       y.numero,
       y.setor,
       y.tipo
  FROM (SELECT d.conjunto,
               d.tipo_conteudo,
               d.tipo_descricao,
               ISNULL(d.pai, d.filho) AS id
          FROM dados d) x
 PIVOT (MAX(tipo_conteudo) FOR tipo_descricao IN (ordem, ano, mes, numero, setor, tipo)) y;
```

Note também que ajustei o nome da coluna `ordem` para `tipo_conteudo` para corresponder ao resultado que você especificou como desejado na pergunta. A coluna `tipo` não foi utilizada na `subquery` justamente para não dividir os resultados mais do que o desejado.

Você pode conferir o resultado em funcionamento no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a58ab/5).

---

> [**`ISNULL`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Substitui `NULL` pelo valor de substituição especificado.

---

> [**`GROUP BY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Agrupa um conjunto de linhas selecionadas em um conjunto de linhas de resumo pelos valores de uma ou mais colunas ou expressões no `SQL Server 2014`. Uma linha é retornada para cada grupo. As funções de agregação na lista de `<seleção>` da cláusula `SELECT` fornecem informações sobre cada grupo em vez de linhas individuais.

---

> [**Usando `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Você pode usar os operadores relacionais `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT` para alterar uma expressão com valor de tabela em outra tabela. `PIVOT` gira uma expressão com valor de tabela ao transformar os valores exclusivos de uma coluna na expressão em colunas múltiplas na saída, além de executar agregações onde forem necessárias em quaisquer valores de coluna remanescentes que sejam desejados na saída final. `UNPIVOT` executa a operação oposta a `PIVOT`, girando colunas de uma expressão com valor de tabela em valores de coluna.

---

> [**`MAX`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187751(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o valor máximo na expressão.