# Em uma query SQL, trazer valores de linhas em uma só linha, em campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer um *query* que traga valores de 2 linhas em uma só Ex:

```
id     | valor   |  banco
000001 | 1000,00 |  caixa
000001 | 1000,00 |  bradesco
```

Preciso que saia assim:

```
id     |  valor   | banco 1 | banco 2
000001 |  1000,00 | caixa   | bradesco
```

No caso preciso que retorne os valores em uma linha separando por campos.

Comment: Qual banco? MySQL, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, Oracle? Cada um tem uma forma diferente de fazer isso o que voce quer. Especifique melhor.

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Comment: não faz muito sentido trazer saldos em colunas, mas ok... e o nome disso é pivot table, tente alguma das perguntas já realizadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+pivot+table

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Transformar linhas em coluna de um select - PIVOT - SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239506/transformar-linhas-em-coluna-de-um-select-pivot-sql-server)

Comment: Olha, não deve ser difícil fazer o que você quer. O problema é que como você não explicou direito, não dá para saber o que você quer e portanto não dá para responder a pergunta. Eu até tentei elaborar uma resposta, mas falta muita coisa em sua pergunta para que isso seja possível. Os bancos são sempre caixa e bradesco? O valor das duas contas é sempre o mesmo? Se os valores divergirem, o que deve ser feito? Qual é o nome da tabela? Quais campos são a chave primária? Há outras tabelas relacionadas? Se houverem mais de dois bancos para o mesmo id, como eu relaciono os registros?

Comment: Você sabe quantos bancos vão ter? Ou vai ser variável?

Comment: Há alguma coluna que indique a ordem das linhas, para um mesmo valor de id? Ou tanto faz vir "caixa | bradesco" ou "bradesco | caixa"?

Answer (score 3):

> *Estou precisando fazer um query que traga valores de 2 linhas em uma só*

Supondo que exista coluna `seq` que indique a ordem das linhas, por valor de `id`, e que `id` identifique cada par de forma única, eis uma sugestão:

```
-- código #1
SELECT id, valor,
       max(case when seq = 1 then banco end) as [banco 1],
       max(case when seq = 2 then banco end) as [banco 2]
  from nome_tabela
  group by id, valor;
```

Mas caso não exista a coluna `seq` e tanto faça a ordem em que os nomes do bancos sejam listados, eis outra opção:

```
-- código #2
with tabela_seq as (
SELECT *,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by id order by (SELECT 0))
  from nome_tabela  
)
SELECT id, valor,
       max(case when seq = 1 then banco end) as [banco 1],
       max(case when seq = 2 then banco end) as [banco 2]
  from tabela_seq
  group by id, valor;
```

Nos dois códigos acima deve-se substituir `nome_tabela` pelo nome da tabela que contém os dados.

---

> *Vou melhorar minha pegunta, (...)
>
>   O campo RECPAG define o banco que paga = p e o que recebe = R,*

Eis o código #1 atualizado, considerando-se as informações adicionais:

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT NUM, VALOR, DATA,
       max(case when RECPAG = 'P' then BANCO end) as [BANCO P],
       max(case when RECPAG = 'R' then BANCO end) as [BANCO R],
       TIPO
  from nome_tabela
  group NUM, VALOR, DATA, TIPO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou melhorar minha pegunta,

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta em SQL server EX:

NUM | VALOR | DATA | RECPAG| BANCO | TIPO

00001| 990,00 | 03042018 | P | SANTANDER | TR

00001| 990,00 | 03042018 | R | BRADESCO | TR

00002| 100,00 | 04052018 | P | BRASIL | TR

00002| 100,00 | 04052018 | R | CAIXA | TR

00003| 200,00 | 05052018 | P | SANTANDER | TR

00003| 200,00 | 05052018 | R | CAIXA | TR

O campo RECPAG define o banco que paga = p e o que recebe = R,

preciso unificar em um linha EX:

NUM | VALOR | DATA | BANCO P| BANCO R | TIPO

00001| 990,00 | 03042018 | SANTANDER| BRADESCO | TR

00002| 100,00 | 04052018 | BRASIL | CAIXA | TR

00003| 200,00 | 05052018 | SANTANDER | CAIXA | TR